# Neo4j Community 3.2.5 - Missing APOC procedures

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Command `CALL dbms.procedures()` shows the standard 25 dbms procedures, cannot see APOC procedures. Any call to these procedures outputs an error saying that it cannot find it and to check spelling, etc.

Neo4j Community 3.2.5

Added `apoc-3.2.3.5-all.jar` fils in `/plugins` folder as listed in start prompt below:

```
Active database: cnaf_v1_20171218.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5
  config:       /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/conf
  logs:         /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/logs
  plugins:      /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/plugins
  import:       /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/import
  data:         /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/data
  certificates: /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/certificates
  run:          /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/run
Starting Neo4j.
Started neo4j (pid 44178). It is available at ...    There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
See /data/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.2.5/logs/neo4j.log for current status.
```

Relevant `conf/neo4j.conf` file settings:

```
# The name of the database to mount
dbms.active_database=cnaf_v1_20171218.db

# Paths of directories in the installation.
dbms.directories.plugins=plugins

# added these based on other stack overflow APOC-based posts
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

Other:

```
$ ls -al plugins/
total 7104
drwxr-xr-x  2 neo4j neo4j      34 Jan 17 14:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 neo4j neo4j    4096 Jan 17 15:22 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 neo4j neo4j 7270364 Jan 17 14:06 apoc-3.2.3.5-all.jar
```

Comment: Are you using Docker?

Comment: No, I'm not using Docker

Comment: Also, have you restarted Neo4j after putting the jar file in the /plugins folder, right?

Comment: Of course, prior any modification (either adding the .jar file or modifying a configuration parameter) I `./bin/neo4j stop`, perfom modification and then `./bin/neo4j start` Neo4j.

Comment: I concur, I am running Neo4j version 3.4.1 and installed APOC 3.4.0.1 manually. I downloaded the .jar file and updated .config as well. I then started Neo4j instance with `neo4j console` command and still cannot see the APOC stored procedures.